Replace libc.so on rooted Android 13
I want to replace libc.so on my rooted Android 13.
remount did not work, what are my options?
panther:/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic # file libc.so
libc.so: ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB arm64, for Android 33, BuildID=cbc4c62a9b269839456f1d7728d8411e, not stripped


Modifying data in an apex (Pony Express) update isn't that easy. For installing a CA certificate as root CA certificate (also delivered as apex update) on Android 14/15 there is a Magisk module available: https://github.com/pwnlogs/cert-fixer May be you can reuse something form that module for your problem.

Bind mount your new file on the existing one.
